# Repository with latest builds for centos 7

Tags: centos, yum

I know that Centos has all the packages kind of old for some reason; you do not need to clarify advantages of this approach to me. I want to use new packages on my experimental machine to analyze our C++ codebase using latest tools and to ensure forward compatibility in case of future upgrade of compiler, etc.

BUT. Are there any repositories that provide up-to-date packages for Centos 7? For example gcc 7 or 8, cmake 3.4, git 2, clang 6 or 7, etc. I know that I can download rpms or build from sources but resolving all of the dependencies takes a lot of time.

Comment: You have the SCL repository which maintains a few selected packages: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL . If you want more cutting-edge packages, you're probably better off moving to another distro.

Comment: @Haxiel Thanks. SCL is awesome, but after some experiments I see that some scripts have trouble with correct detection of version of installed packages when using SCL (Yes, I am using SCL the way it is supposed to be used, the scripts are just checking versions wrong way). Based on my knowledge, it should be possible to port software from Centos to Fedora. I will try this option.